# Selenium test fails on build server with "No response from server" error

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I have a simple Selenium test within VS2010 test project as follows.

```
[TestMethod]  
public void MyTestInIE8()  
{  
    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();  
    try  
    {  
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/MyMVC/ABC/DoStuff");
       driver.FindElement((By.Id("Name"))).SendKeys("John");  
       //... run rest of the test  
    }  
    finally  
    {  
       driver.Quit();  
    }  
}
```

This runs fine on the local server. However on the build server it fails with the following message.
 ...threw exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: No response from server for url http://localhost:4444/session/5e5e9b7a-e05c-40d8-9a20-9cab138b2b87.

The problem seems to be calling the Quit() method in the finally clause. I tried to pass in a known port number, i.e. InternetExplorerDriver(8080), but it made no difference. Firefox driver runs fine both locally and on the build server. I found someone reporting similar issue but did not find a working solution. http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/msg/4347971da4d96e97

Here is my config.
Windows 7 professional SP1, 64 bit.
Webdriver - selenium-dotnet-2.0b2.
IE8.

My build server is Windows Server2008 R2 Standard with IE8.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this issue fixed. Even i am facing same issue on same environment.

Answer (score 5):

The Internet Explorer driver requires some configuration of IE as documented in the [project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver). You will need to make sure that the browser is configured properly on your build server.

The Selenium project has been updated recently to throw a more useful error in the case where the IE driver isn't configured properly. Updating to [2.0rc2](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) will give you this more useful error.

Comment: Did as you suggested and now it gives the error,                                                   System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (NoSuchDriver). I have IE 9 installed on the build server. Tried enabling all zones as well as disabling all zones. Zoom was set at 100%.   Incidently Firefox fails on the build server with, OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: No response from server for url 
http://localhost:7055/hub/session/feb99703-822e-4b59-892a-884e3d28b66...

Comment: We found out that the a/c used to run the builds was not authenticated on the proxy server whereas my own account was. The proxy server might  have come into the picture as we recently started using CDN's to pull down jQuery. So bypassing the proxy server (using internet options on the browser) sorted the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well and the solution I found was to wait a little while after using the `FindElement()` method before acting on the element.

Something like this:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name"))
Thread.Sleep(200);
element.SendKeys("John");
```

Apparently there are some race conditions caused by the driver. Or that's my guess anyway.