# Internet Explorer automated testing using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, testing, user-interface, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been looking into using tools for UI testing automatically and seem to have ran into a problem at the first hurdle with Selenium.

It was my understanding that if you used the WebDriver that there was no need for you to setup a Selenium server or anything like this. Basically, all I want to do is create an instance locally of Internet Explorer and control it.

Using this very basic code taken;

```
var ie = new InternetExplorerDriver();
ie.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.co.uk");
```

I get the following error on the first line;

```
No response from server for url http://localhost:64333/session
```

Based on this statement, I am not sure what else I need to do just to get this instance;

> Once your project is set up, you can see that WebDriver acts just as
>   any normal library: it is entirely self-contained, and you usually
>   don’t need to remember to start any additional processes or run any
>   installers before using it, as opposed to the proxy server with
>   Selenium-RC.

Suggestions would be appreciated as the WatIn option has come to a halt and I need to see if Selenium can cope with a specific problem in our solution.

Thanks

Comment: I have not worked on c#. Tried the same code in java and it works        InternetExplorerDriver ie = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  ie.navigate().to("www.google.co.uk");

Comment: @A.J Yes, exactly what I thought should happen on my machine. I have no idea why it would attempt to connect to that prior to doing what I want.

Comment: What version of selenium are you using?

Comment: @nilesh 2.9 at the moment, not sure if there are later versions, will check.

Comment: Updated to 2.11 and same problem occurs.

Comment: It looks like a proxy issue, similar to this thread-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271473/selenium-test-fails-on-build-server-with-no-response-from-server-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured IE correctly (seems to be the only driver which needs configuration). - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: Yes, all zones are the same. Have tried both protected and not, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("www.google.co.uk");
```

You may also want to turn off UAC and retest if you are stilling seeing this.

Answer (score 0):

**Selenium WebDriver C# in InternetExplorerDriver:**

**Prerequisite:** Install Visual Studio (mine is VS 2017), IE browser

Steps to follow:

1. Open VS 2017 and create solution/project
2. Write a test using C# code as below:

   IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("Your Test URL");

Now install "Selenium.InternetExplorer.WebDriver" by following steps:

1. Right click on Project -> Manage NuGet Packages...
2. Click Browse at the top and search for InternetExplorer
3. Select "Selenium.InternetExplorer.WebDriver" from the search list and install it
4. Execute/Run your test

Comment: The same procedure is applicable for Visual Studio 2015