# Selenium IE Driver stalls intermittently during remote execution

Tags: .net, selenium, webdriver, virtual-machine

*I was under the impression this was a common issue that people faced when using Selenium, but was surprised to only find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271473/selenium-test-fails-on-build-server-with-no-response-from-server-error). The question only addresses an older version of Selenium and suggests a crude 'sleep wait' be placed, which has not worked for me thus far.*

A fantastic explanation of what my issue is can be found at the [following blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/net-bindings-whaddaymean-no-response.html) in good detail. 
Briefly, when I run remote tests with Selenium WebDriver at seemingly sporadic times I am getting some tests that stall. By stall I mean the browser window closes and the driver (IEDriverServer in this case) keeps running indefinitely until it is manually killed.

Want I would like to know is has anyone found a work around? I need either the WebDriver process to be killed upon this '*no response from url*' exception first occuring or for it to be avoided entirely. Currently the browser closes, but the driver hangs until manually closed through remote connection.

Some other potentially useful information:

- Tests are being run on **IE7** generally and at times **IE8** *(appears to stall more frequently on 7, but this might just be coincidence and I can't back this up with data)*.
- Stalling happens on different tests from build to build, but those that stall are a subset of the entire test suite.
- I am running my tests on a **XP Client** machine that is accessing our deployed page on a **Windows 2008 R2 server**. These machines are in the same **Lab Management Environment *(2010)***.
- For a while I was not getting any tests to stall. However, with no check-ins to the solution, tests have begun to stall intermittently.
- I am writing my tests in **C#** and am using the **Selenium .NET Bindings**, **WebDriver 2.28.0** with the **IEDriverServer.exe**.
- Tests are being run via a TestAgent on the client with the QTAgent.exe process which communicates with the Test Controller.

Some key things I have attempted:

- Implemented a javascript error detector that will report to a log (empty on stalled tests).
- All actions on elements are preceeded by a waitForElementToExist call (5 sec max).
- Tests do not stall locally.
- An extra sleep wait around seemingly problem areas in tests.
- Recreation of the Environment.

Alternatively, if there is no direct workaround to prevent tests from stalling, a solution that will kill a test that has stalled would also be welcomed as an answer.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on exactly what the problem is here. Are you receiving an exception in your tests, or is the problem that IEDriverServer.exe is not properly shutting down when you close the browser via WebDriver, or both? Also, when you say you are "run[ning] remote tests," does that mean you're using RemoteWebDriver in conjunction with the Java Selenium server, or some other mechanism?

Comment: Valid questions, have edited for more clarity (hopefully). Good to see the original blog poster reply! To answer you directly here the Driver is not properly shutting down upon some event and hangs causing tests to stop until it is manually killed. I am using a TFS build to run my tests which execute the IEDriverServer.exe which is stored on the client box.

Comment: Okay, one final follow up question: How is the browser getting closed? The IE driver itself has no mechanism for automatically closing instances of IE. That means either your code is attempting to shut down the browser on a failure, the browser itself is crashing silently, or the agent process executing the test code is trying to be clever. Which is it?

Comment: Upon an exception or failed assert the Test will jump to the 'Cleanup()' method which will call Selenium's 'driver.Quit()'. I am under the impression this is what is closing the browser as I am getting an exception in my test results. However, this is supposed to kill the Driver too. I do not attempt to kill the browser any other way.

Comment: Double-check your `Cleanup()` method to make sure you're using `driver.Quit()` and not just `driver.Close()`. They aren't equivalent, despite what the docs might appear to claim.

Comment: Is definitely driver.Quit(), I originally was using Close() a long time ago and made the switch in order to better close everything (browser + driver).